# How to use vba get weekday name of a cell

Tags: vba

I ran this code but it shows type missmatch error.  The orginal data i have is 20181101

```
ws.Cells.Item(2, i).Value = WeekdayName(Weekday(ws.Cells.Item(1, i), 0), False, 0)
```

Comment: Is your original data (`20181101`) stored as text or as a number?  (That's not a standard date format.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your data (ie., `20181101`) is stored as text or a number, but not as a an Excel date.

Try this instead:

```
Dim dt_Str As String, dt As Date
dt_Str = ws.Cells.Item(1, i)
dt = DateValue(Left(dt_Str, 4) & "/" & Mid(dt_Str, 5, 2) & "/" & Right(dt_Str, 2))
ws.Cells.Item(2, i).Value = WeekdayName(Weekday(dt))
```